# Javascript count up animation stops counting with comma

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to add a count up animation using javascript on my page. I've been able to get a working solution but the counter stops working if the number has a comma for example : `53,210` the counter will display `53`. How can I be able to have the counter animation with numbers that have a comma?

Here is a code snippet :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  runAnimations();
};

// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 2000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration );
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );



// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = el => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 );
    // Start the animation running 60 times per second
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame++;
        // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
        // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
        // progress on a curve
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );
        // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
        const currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );

        // If the current count has changed, update the element
        if ( parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 ) !== currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount;
        }

        // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};


// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach( animateCountUp );
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53,210</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am expecting the HTML to display the full number of `53,210` with the count up animation. Not stop at the number before the comma.

Comment: `integer` numbers do not have commas.  You can display them in a human-readable format to make it easier to *see* the thousands, and millions, etc. but for computers, this is not needed.  You could simply use a number w/o delimiters (commas) for the calculations and display them with delimiters for humans to see

Answer (score 2):

Need to parseInt with comma. :

```
parseInt(el.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ''), 10)
```

Also display with comma need to following line change.

```
el.innerHTML = currentCount.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Check following code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  runAnimations();
};

// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 2000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration );
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );



// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = el => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseInt(el.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
    // Start the animation running 60 times per second
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame++;
        // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
        // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
        // progress on a curve
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );
        // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
        const currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );

        // If the current count has changed, update the element
        if ( parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 ) !== currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

        // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};


// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach( animateCountUp );
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53,210</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.toLocaleString('en-US');` to your `const currentCount`  so that animation contain a comma according to US number system .
[See this for .toLocaleString('en-US');](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

If you want to use comma in the class also than use `.replace(',', '')` to remove comma when function values are entered . Also if values contain more than 1 comma than use global attribute in like this `.replace(/\,/g, '')`
[See this for Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  runAnimations();
};

// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 2000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = Math.round(animationDuration / frameDuration);
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * (2 - t);



// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = el => {
  let frame = 0;
  const countTo = parseInt(el.innerHTML.replace(/\,/g, ''), 10);
  // Start the animation running 60 times per second
  const counter = setInterval(() => {
    frame++;
    // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
    // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
    // progress on a curve
    const progress = easeOutQuad(frame / totalFrames);
    // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
    const currentCount = Math.round(countTo * progress).toLocaleString('en-US');;

    // If the current count has changed, update the element
    if (parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10) !== currentCount) {
      el.innerHTML = currentCount;
    }

    // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
    if (frame === totalFrames) {
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, frameDuration);
};


// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
  const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll('.countup');
  countupEls.forEach(animateCountUp);
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53,210</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">5,3,2,1,0</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53,215480</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the `,` from the input before proceeding with the rest of the code.  Something along the lines of:

```
  // get input as string from HTML
  const formattedNumber = el.innerHTML;
  
  // Format as number input (removes commas)
  const inputNumber = formattedNumber.replace(/\,/g,'');
  const countTo = new Number(inputNumber);
```

**See demo**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  runAnimations();
};

// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 2000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = Math.round(animationDuration / frameDuration);
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * (2 - t);



// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = el => {
  let frame = 0;
  
  // get input as string from HTML
  const formattedNumber = el.innerHTML;
  
  // Format as number input (removes commas)
  const inputNumber = formattedNumber.replace(/\,/g,'');
  const countTo = new Number(inputNumber);
  
  // Start the animation running 60 times per second
  const counter = setInterval(() => {
    frame++;
    // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
    // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
    // progress on a curve
    const progress = easeOutQuad(frame / totalFrames);
    // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
    const currentCount = Math.round(countTo * progress);

    // If the current count has changed, update the element
    if (parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10) !== currentCount) {
      el.innerHTML = currentCount;
    }

    // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
    if (frame === totalFrames) {
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, frameDuration);
};


// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
  const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll('.countup');
  countupEls.forEach(animateCountUp);
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53,210</span></li>
</ul>
```