# Using GSAP and ScrollTrigger to create a number counter (where numbers exist)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrolltrigger

I have a `section` which showcases statistics.

- Some of these statistics are numbers (i.e. 145);
- Some are numbers, characters and symbols (i.e. 65K+ or $20.00)
- Some are just purely text (i.e. "text")

When this section is in `view`, I want stats which contain a number to count up (and naturally stats that don't contain numbers to not count up).

The effect I'm trying to achieve is:

- All `.statsBannerCard`'s are set to `visibility: hidden`
- User scrolls to section
- JS checks if first `.statsBannerCard` contains number; if yes, counts up (this single card is `visibility: visible` now).
- Then once the counter for the first card is complete, make the second card visible and check if it contains a number, and so on.

The proceeding card is essentially shown once the previous card counter is complete. If a card just contains text (so we can't count up), it will just show the card and move on.

Current issue:

In my demo below, I'm using the `data-number` attribute to determine what number the card needs to count up to. When scrolling down, the first counter works (because it is a pure `integer`), however, it stops working when characters, symbols or letters are involved.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);


  $(".statsBannerCard__statistic").each(function(index, element) {
    var count = $(this),
      zero = {
        val: 0
      },
      num = count.data("number"),
      split = (num + "").split("."), // to cover for instances of decimals
      decimals = split.length > 1 ? split[1].length : 0;

    gsap.to(zero, {
      val: num,
      duration: 2,
      scrollTrigger: element,
      onUpdate: function() {
        count.text(zero.val.toFixed(decimals));
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.spacer{
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.statsBanner{
  background: #F283D6;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.statsBanner__intro{
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.statsBannerCard{
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<section class="spacer">
  Scroll down
</section>


<section class="statsBanner">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="statsBanner__intro text-center">
          <h2>Start counter when this section is in view.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-evenly">


      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="145">145</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="Text">Text</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="$20,000">$20,000</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="60K+">60K+</span>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are your friends

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursive function to process the stats one by one. Use `onComplete` function call to process next stat. Explanation is in code comments:

```js
$(function() {

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  //get stats in array to process one by one
  let stats = $(".statsBannerCard__statistic").toArray();

  //recursive function
  function countOne(stats) {
    if (stats.length < 1) { //when all stats done exit
      return;
    }
    let stat = stats.shift(); //remove first

    //make the card visible
    $(stat).parent().css({
      visibility: 'visible'
    });

    var count = $(stat),
      zero = {
        val: 0
      },
      num = count.data("number"),
      split = (num + "").split("."), // to cover for instances of decimals
      decimals = split.length > 1 ? split[1].length : 0;

    //if it's not a number then skip counting
    if (typeof num == 'number') {
      gsap.to(zero, {
        val: num,
        duration: 2,
        scrollTrigger: stat,
        onUpdate: function() {
          let numText = zero.val.toFixed(decimals)
          numText = numText.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
          count.text(numText);
        },
        onComplete: function() {
          countOne(stats);
        }
      });

    } else {
      count.text(num);
      countOne(stats);
    }
  }

  //initiate
  countOne(stats);
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.statsBanner {
  background: #F283D6;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.statsBanner__intro {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.statsBannerCard {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<section class="spacer">
  Scroll down
</section>


<section class="statsBanner">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="statsBanner__intro text-center">
          <h2>Start counter when this section is in view.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-evenly">

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="145">145</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="Text">Text</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          $<span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="20000">20,000</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="60">60</span>K+
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

To properly handle currencies you'll have to use some library or special implementation. Here, I've cut corners for the demo.

 Refer [how to convert currency string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/559112/15273968) 
And [how to format number to currency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149055/15273968)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution(but without counting animation).

The function is triggered when `element` comes into view. [Can view in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70424567/16846346)

For counting animation you [can refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227592/16846346)

```js
let statistic = document.querySelectorAll(".statsBannerCard__statistic");
let valueArr = [];
let trueOnlyOnce = true;
let i = 0;

statistic.forEach(e => valueArr.push(e.dataset.number))

let statsBanner = document.querySelector(".statsBanner");
document.addEventListener('scroll', animationTrigger);

function animationTrigger() {
  if (window.scrollY >= statsBanner.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight && trueOnlyOnce) {
    trueOnlyOnce = false;
    animationCounter();
  }
}

function animationCounter() {
  if (i < statistic.length) {
    if (valueArr[i].replace(/[^\d]/g, '') !== "") {
      statistic[i].innerHTML = "0";
      statistic[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      setTimeout(function() {
        statistic[i].innerHTML = valueArr[i];
        i = i + 1;
        animationCounter();
      }, 2000)
    } else if (valueArr[i].replace(/[^\d]/g, '') == "") {
      statistic[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      i = i + 1;
      animationCounter();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.statsBanner {
  background: #F283D6;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.statsBanner__intro {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.statsBannerCard {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<section class="spacer">
  Scroll down
</section>


<section class="statsBanner">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="statsBanner__intro text-center">
          <h2>Start counter when this section is in view.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-evenly">


      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="145">145</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="Text">Text</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="$20,000">$20,000</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="statsBannerCard text-center">
          <span class="statsBannerCard__statistic" data-number="60K+">60K+</span>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```